# Error in SherlockFragment when switching items in slide Menu

Tags: android, view, actionbarsherlock, fragment, addchild

I'm having lot of problems when implementing ActionBar Sherlock, the last one is this one. I have an Slide Menu whith 3 options in my ActionBar. My problem is that when I choose one item (it load a fragment) that has been previously selected the app crash. The log error is

> The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView()
>   on the child's parent first.

It mark a line where I add view to a HorizontalScroller.

```
lls.addView(mviews.get(i));
```

In my OnCreateView I have

```
final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_landing, container,false);
```

`container.removeAllViews();`

I haved tried many different ways posted here, but I don't get thw solution to my problem. Any ideas?

EDIT:
Here is some code of my MainActivity and Fragment.

This is the MainActivity. Ther's a ScreenSplash after and a class that extends from Application that control all WebService communications.

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity  {


    //Declare Variables
    //...
     Fragment fragment1 = new Fragment1();
     Fragment fragment2 = new Fragment2();
     Fragment fragment3 = new Fragment3();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");          
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer_main);


        // Generate title
        title = new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" };

        // Generate icon
        icon = new int[] { R.drawable.item1, R.drawable.item2,
                R.drawable.item3, R.drawable.item4};

        // Locate DrawerLayout in drawer_main.xml
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        // Locate ListView in drawer_main.xml
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // Set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
        // opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);

        // Pass results to MenuListAdapter Class
        mMenuAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(this, title, subtitle, icon);

        // Set the MenuListAdapter to the ListView
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mMenuAdapter);

        // Capture button clicks on side menu
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // Enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close) {

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }



    }


    //FOR ABS y ND
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
      //Define ActionBar buttons and actions 

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        //Sliding lateral Menu
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // The click listener for ListView in the navigation drawer
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        // Locate Position
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment1);
            break;
        case 1:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment2);
            break;
        case 2:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment3);
            break;
        }
        ft.commit();
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        // Close drawer
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

This is the fragment with error. Now the other two are empty.

```
public class Fragment1 extends SherlockFragment implements
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

//DeclareVariables

public Fragment1() {
}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //some declaration ad settings (witdhs, typefaces, caches,...)   

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_activity, null,
            false);
    container.removeAllViews();
    lls = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.lscroll_item);
    lls.removeAllViews();
            //Instantiate some elements of the view such as TextViews and ImageViews
            //layoutParams

    // Show Scroll 
    DataStore.sharedInstance().getInfo(
            new DataStore.infoReturn() {

        @Override
        public void call(final ArrayList<User> users, int error) {
            if(users != null){                  

                for (i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {

                            mviews.add((RelativeLayout) getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_user, null));
                            mviews.get(i).setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);
                            imv = (ImageView) mviews.get(i).findViewById(R.id.user);
                            imv.getLayoutParams().height=friend_height;
                            imv_click = (ImageView) mviews.get(i).findViewById(R.id.click);
                            TextView text2 = (TextView) mviews.get(i).findViewById(R.id.fav);
                            text2.setTypeface(myTypeFace);
                                                            //set widths and layoutParams and sources



                            mviews.get(i).setId(i);
                                                            //NEXT LINE IS THE CRASH POINT, WHERE I TRY TO ADD ITEMS TO THE VIEW
                            lls.addView(mviews.get(i));

                            mviews.get(i).setOnClickListener(
                                    new OnClickListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            //Set actins when click
                                        }
                                    });

                        }
            }else{

                switch (error) {
                case -1: //ERROR OBTENER USERS                      
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }

            }
                }
            });



@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // actions when click

}

 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        refreshInfo();
            refreshSelectedUsers();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        DataStore.sharedInstance().setSelectedUsers(mSelected);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        //delete cache

    }



   //Some other methods for other UI items.
```

}

I have hidden some code to make it easier to read.

Comment: I am not sure about it, but I think that you are complicating your code. Try to use a ListView with an adapter instead of you LineraLayout lls. The problem is that you are calling the method public void call(final ArrayList<User> users, int error) more than one time. The first time works fine because the rows you are adding match with the order. The second time, you are adding new rows but still adding the first one due to mviews.get(i). I think the best you can do is change this and look the monster that you have created :)
for (i = mItems.size; i < mItems.size+users.size(); i++)

Comment: @Juangcg but my lls is the LinearLayout inside of a HorizontalScrollView. After some tries I concluded it was the best way to show some Images (I don't now how many at the begining) y an horizontal scroll, bigger than the screen. Actually they are not only images but a relative layout compounds by images and textviews

Comment: How many times is this function called? public void call(final ArrayList<User> users, int error)

Comment: Each time I go to this Activity. Maybe I should call only once, but I don't know how to save an instance of all this views.

Comment: Try to check if views are already added before calling that function. Something like this: if(mViews==null || mViews.length == 0) call function.

Comment: @Juangcg As I told you before I was using 3 fragmentes for the same activity basing on an example, but what I wanted was navigate through different Activities, each one with its fragment. Well, I implemented my navigation with Activities and I don't get the error if I go to another activity and return back to home. But, when my home Activity is called (intent) from another one it crashed again, not in the same line, but also for mviews. Now maybe it's because it's not correctly initialized How could I save an instance of the view, so I can use it when OnResume my Activity again? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Juangcg So, you know How could I save an instance of the activity view, so I can use it when OnResume my Activity again? I have the same problem when my app goes to background and then I try to restart, it crash.

Comment: you need to save the state in this function: protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState); Take a look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Juangcg . I read a lot about this, but I don't get what I need. When I pass from Home Activity to another activity and return with Back Button everything is ok. The problem is when I go to Home Activity through an intent it runs OncreateView again (download data, configure View, etc) and it take so much time that is not good to user experience. I understood that onSaveinstanceState could be usefull to safe some states of the View, such us some value displayed. But I would like to save the whole View so it doesn't need to "createView" again.

Comment: I have the same problem with another activity that has two tabs (with two fragments). I shouldn't oncreateView each time I switch from one tab to another.

Comment: Sorry, but this is going beyond the objective of Stackoverflow. This is for specific questions not for personal tutoring. I hope you will find this information useful.

Comment: Ok, maybe you are right. Thanks for your ideas anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_landing, null, false);
```

instead of

```
final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_landing, container,false);
```

Comment: Thanks Juangcg, I've tried it but still, the same error. I'll try to give more details of my view parent-child structure:

Comment: (sorry, I sent unintentionally) Thanks Juangcg, I've tried it but still, the same error. I'll try to give more details of my view parent-child structure: I have the view "v" as the upper parent. In this view I have a LinearLayout "lls" and a ListView. In the linearLayout I have "mviews", an array of Views (RelativeLayouts) that makes an Horizontal Scroll View. The line that Log is marking, is when I add mviews[] to "lls". Hope it's more clear. Any help will be welcome since it's my first time with ActionBar an have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: The error that you are receiving means that one of your horizontal scroll view is already added when you try to add to your list. I need to see more code to help you. By the way, when you say 3 options you mean 3 tabs?

Comment: For example, are the mviews shared between fragments? How do you handle the tab click event?

Comment: Ok, sorry, let's try to explain better. When I say options I mean the options of the lateral menu in Navigation Drawer , such as new gmail app (you can see [link](http://www.iamwire.com/2013/05/googles-new-navigation-drawer-for-android-leaked-out/) ). Each option drive you to different activities, with each fragment) . So, If I'm in home activity and navigate to other one with the menu, then when I try to navigate back to home it crash. mviews are not shared with any other fragment.

Comment: I have avoided the error with  this code `if(mviews.size()!=0){
 ((ViewGroup) mviews.get(0).getParent()).removeAllViews();
}`  So I wanted to avoid instantiate mviews again through another parent. But this is not a good solution, since I have to create the complete view again (including call to a WebService to bring some data to build the View)

Comment: I've noticed that now every fragment has the same context , the MainActivity one), as I haven't implemented the rest. I took a very example on the web to implement the NavigationDrawer and I wanted to implement each option one by one. Taking in account than when I didn't use this navigation I didn't have this problem, maybe it could be the reason? I'll try implementing all fragments for different activities

Comment: As I told you, the problem is that those views are already added to another parent. Where do you call lls.addView(mviews.get(i))? Do you have setRetainInstance set to true?

Comment: Ok, but I have no a clear idea where are also used. Anyway, I haven't set setRetainInstance to rue, should I?

Comment: No, you don't have to. I will need to see some of your code to help you.

Comment: Juangcg I've done it. I've hiden some code cause it was too long, but tell me if you think there's something important hidden. I tried to hide only code not regarded with the error.